# How can contents of a namespace be made available to an entire project without generating Multiply Defined Symbol errors?

Tags: c++, namespaces, linker-errors, lnk2005

I am attempting to make a fairly large video game, and my current method of handling mouse input is to pass mouseX, mouseY, and an enum mouseState as arguments to the update function of EVERY single object that requires knowledge of the mouse. It's fairly messy, and I want to make the mouse variables more global by putting them in a namespace called Input so that I can access them with Input::mouseX, et al.

As it stands now, The namespace Input exists in Input.h (contents below)

```
#pragma once
#include "allegro5\allegro.h"
#include "J_Enum.h"
namespace Input{
ALLEGRO_EVENT_QUEUE *inputQueue;
int mouseX;
int mouseY;
MOUSE_STATE mouseState;
void setUpInput();
void updateInput();
};
```

and the two member functions are defined in Input.cpp

```
#include "Input.h"

void Input::setUpInput(){...declaration
void Input::updateInput(){...''
```

Upon including Input.h in the main loop object's header *Core.h* the linker throws a hissy fit because in its eyes everything included in Input.h is now a Multiply Defined Symbol.
Clearly something is wrong with my use of header files, because to my knowledge, I haven't made any glaring mistakes in my use of namespaces and the error code prefix of LNK2005 seems to implicate the linker(?).

If anyone can possibly shed some light on my dilemma I would be most grateful

Comment: Does it work when you use header guard?

Answer (score 2):

Declare the variables as `extern`:

```
// header file:
namespace Input {
  extern int mouseX;
}

// implementation
#include "input.h"
namespace Input {
  int mouseX;
}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. You are my hero of the day, yet I find myself unable to rep you as I have not yet got the 15 required to do so.

Comment: @JayH: No worries (I'm over my daily cap anyway). You do get reputation for "accept"ing an answer, though :-)